# Google drag and drop not working

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag and drop div, like [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/07/Drag-and-drop-a-folder-onto-Chrome-now-available). Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, when I try to drag to this div, a new tab with the selected file opens.
Here is my code

```
    <div id="dropzone" style="height:200px; border: 4px double black;" ></div>
    <script>
        window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
        var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
        dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
          var length = e.dataTransfer.items.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var entry = e.dataTransfer.items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
            if (entry.isFile) {
               // do whatever you want
            } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
               // do whatever you want
            }
          }
        };
  </script>
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dropbox;
dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox");
dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
  
function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;
  handleFiles(files);
}
```

```css
#dropbox
{
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px double black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  font: 5em bold monospace;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropbox">
  Drag files here!
</div>
```

The Google link is outdated, but [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) allows the file system to work in a very similar fashion. An example of this is above.